# HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I'm transforming data using python and then persisting it to S3, but when I try and create a   table on Athena I get a HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR. If I cast the amount fields to varchar it works but the dashboarding tools like quicksight and grafana cannot process them efficiently.

Python

```
        wr.s3.to_parquet(df=df,path=s3path)
```

JSON

```
{
  "id": 9454463292,
  "version": 1,
  "player_id": "923584",
  "cash_stake": 0.27,
  "cash_win": 0,
  "bonus_stake": 0,
  "bonus_win": 0
}
```

Athena

```
  
  CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `stakes`(
  `id` bigint, 
  `version` bigint, 
  `player_id` varchar(25), 
  `cash_stake` float, 
  `cash_win` float, 
  `bonus_stake` float, 
  `bonus_win` float)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://stakes/b_stakes'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'classification'='parquet', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1690890205')
```